# Will this trigger ASI (Auto Semicolon Insertion)?

Tags: javascript

Will this trigger ASI (Auto Semicolon Insertion)?

```
if (abc === def) {

    doSomething();
} // <-- here
else {  

    doDifferently();
}

try {

    doSomething();
} // <-- here
catch(e) {

    doCatch();
}
```

Comment: What was your intention when posting this? Is this a concern you had??

Comment: I love Allman style. But due to ASI, I have to switch to K&R style. I just feel align "else", or "catch" to same level looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Automatic semicolon insertion only happens between statements, and your examples are not like that.

An `if - else` statement is a **single statement**. Insterting a semicolon there would make absolutely no sense. The semicolon insertion "feature" is all about making sense of a sequence of separate statements that are **not** separated by semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

No - you can structure your curly brackets however you like.